# How can I install python3-dev for armhf using debian multiarch?

Tags: linux, debian, installation, python, package-management

I also posted this question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/77693879/7926069 but was told this site may be a better fit so I crossposted. Hope that's okay!

I have been going in circles trying to install this package as it is a dependency I need for something else (`libboost-all-dev:armhf`).

I have added `armhf` architecture and installed `python3:armhf` just fine. However, whenever I try to install `python3-dev:armhf`, it says it needs `python3-distutils:armhf`. When I try to install `python3-distutils:armhf`, it says

> Note, selecting 'python3-distutils' instead of 'python3-distutils:armhf'

This uninstalls `python3:armhf` and installs `python3:amd64` and its dependencies instead, and this obviously conflicts with `python3:armhf`. How can I resolve this?

I have found these two somewhat related questions, but the answers don't seem to actually resolve the issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332023/debian-multiarch-unable-to-install-python-for-both-armhf-and-amd64

[How to install armhf packages on an x86 host](https://superuser.com/questions/1439855/how-to-install-armhf-packages-on-an-x86-host)

Comment: It's not super okay. Questions can be migrated between the key sites, and they should not be cross posted. If you don't want to deal with the migration, you can delete the question there yourself and leave this one up here.

Comment: @music2myear oh okay. Do you agree that the question fits better in this forum? If so I will delete the other one